# linear algebra and linear functionals

Tags: linear-algebra

Let V a vector space and $dim_\mathbb{K} V = n$. Proof that if m < n and $f_1,..,f_m$ be linear functionals in $\mathscr{L}(V,\mathbb{K}$). Then, there is a vector nonzero $v \in$ V such that $f_i(v)=0$ for $i=1,..,m.$

I am trying to prove the following. Let B = {$v_1,..,v_m,v_{m+1},...,v_n$} a basis of V, I suppose that $\hspace{0.4cm}$ {$f_1,..,f_m$} $\subset$ B* basis of V*.  Then let $v_{m+1}$ $\in$ B, we have that

$f_i(v_{m+1})=0, \hspace{0.5cm}\forall i=1,...n. $

But, if {$f_1,..,f_m$} $\not\subset$ B*? what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The map $T:V \to \Bbb F^m$ defined by
$$
T(v) = (f_1(v),\dots,f_m(v))
$$
is a linear map from the $n$-dimensional space $V$ to the smaller space $\Bbb F^m$.  By the rank-nullity theorem, $T$ cannot have a trivial kernel.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Since $Dim_\mathbb{F} KerT >0 $  then there is a nonzero vector $v \in V$ such that $v \in KerT$, this implies that $f_i(v)=0 \forall i=1,...,m.$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\ker f_i$ has dimension at least $n-1$.
 Use the dimension formula to prove that the intersection of an $n-a$ dimensional subspace with an $n-b$ dimensional subspace has dimension at least $n-(a+b)$. Then use induction.